# C# Saving GIF or JPG.... how to improve the quality?

Tags: c#, gif, jpeg

I screen captured the desktop and saved in jpg and gif

the quality of png file is perfect. However, the quality of jpg and gif seems little bit low... Is there way to improve this?

Comment: For jpg - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, gif doesn't support as much color space as png and jpeg is lossy, so you can't match a png.

Answer (score 0):

You should research the technical aspects of GIF and JPG:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPG

The simplest answer is probably this:  GIF is largely limited to 256 colors so if your screenshot should contain more than that (i.e. a modern desktop or application) you will see dithering of some kind, which will reduce perceived quality.  JPEG is a lossy compression method optimized for photographs, so a screenshot of something not photographic (i.e. a desktop) will show occasionally jarring compression artifacts.